# React useState update is not re-rendering component

Tags: reactjs, react-state

I want to re-render the child component which uses state of parent component as props.

My scenario:
And using a react-slick slider to show images on a page, and it has a prop initial slide accoding which slider show initial slide.
I am using useState() to maintain initialSlide value, There is another trigger on page which updates initialSlide value and when I update initialSlide value it does not re-render react-slider.

Please check demo code below:
[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-o7glmt)

In above demo, click on button> currentSlide value updates> react-slider does not update.

Is there a way to achieve this in react, I tries same using redux store but child component never re-renders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [sliderNext](https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/api/#slickNext) and [sliderPrev](https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/api/#slickPrev) methods. Also to use them you should get ref to slider via [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook.

The example of using that methods: https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/example/previous-next-methods/

The working slider: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bwfh5g

Comment: Hi RukkiesMan, Thanks for answering.
The solution you have given would work if I use the change slide button for going to the next slide. What if I want to go to slide 4 from slide 1? In that case I can't use slickPrev() and slickNext().

Comment: Hi, I got another method for my problem: slickGoTo(), this will work.
Many thanks!

Comment: Cool! Glad you found the solution